first 2 makes query slower than when I use first 1 in select on large table
I have a query on a huge table (over 126 million records) on an informix database server, it returns only one record. When I use "first 1 " in the select statement, it runs quickly but using "first 2" makes it very slow.
Does anybody know how "first" works when the number of result records is less than the number used for "first"?
Here are the query plans:
with first 1:
Estimated Cost: 5195623 
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 4342493 1) 
informix.financialt0_: INDEX PATH (1) 
Index Name: informix.tblpartition_indx_7 
Index Keys: id version (Serial, fragments: ALL) 
Lower Index Filter: informix.financialt0_.id > 70201542 

first 2 :
Estimated Cost: 5195622 
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 4342493 1) 
informix.financialt0_: INDEX PATH (1) 
Index Name: informix.itxnpartition_indx_7 
Index Keys: id version (Serial, fragments: ALL) 
Lower Index Filter: informix.financialt0_.id > 70201542 


Post the query as well as the query plan, and outline schemas for the tables involved.
